# Layout not showing some info

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-xml

[image: image 2][![Image 1]Need help regarding my xml.The problem is I want the venue label (venue) to have the venue name next to it. However any time I run the app nothing shows up for venue.Even from the layout, the Design does not show the venue name text. The blueprint however does (Madison Square Garden).

I clicked the toggle visibilty issue panel for help.
It says "venueName  is partially covered by surface ".
I am new to android. Any help will be highly appreciated.[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
    
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
    
            <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/venueRating"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:isIndicator="true"
                android:numStars="5"
                android:progressTint="@color/colorRating"
                android:rating="3.5"
                android:scaleX="1.5"
                android:scaleY="1.5"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ratingValue"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/title"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/ratingValue"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ratingValue" />
    
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:fontFamily="@font/chivo_bold"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageContainer"
                tools:text="Taylor Swift" />
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ratingValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/rubik_one"
                android:letterSpacing="-0.1"
                android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/imageContainer"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title"
                tools:text="4.2" />
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/event_taxonomies"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:letterSpacing="-0.1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/venueRating"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/venueRating" />
    
            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/half_default_margin"
                android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/event_taxonomies" />
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/venueInfo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/chivo_bold"
                android:text="@string/head_venueInfo"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/divider"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divider"/>
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/venueNameLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:text="@string/venueName"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/venueInfo"/>
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/venueName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_margin"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/venueNameLabel"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/divider"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/venueNameLabel"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/venueNameLabel"
                tools:text="Madison Square Garden"/>
    
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/venueAddressLabel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:text="@string/address"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/venueNameLabel"/>
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/venueStateLabel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:text="@string/state"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/venueAddressLabel"/>
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/venueCapacityLabel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:text="@string/venueCapacity"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/venueStateLabel"/>
    
            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider_"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/half_default_margin"
                android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/venueCapacityLabel" />
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/performerHeader"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:text="@string/performers"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/divider_" />
    
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/performersList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:minHeight="60dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/performerHeader" />
    
            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                android:id="@+id/surface"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="600dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.578" />
    
            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                android:id="@+id/imageContainer"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="210dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="142dp"
                android:elevation="12dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                app:cardElevation="4dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
            </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
    
            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/share"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/default_margin"
                android:contentDescription="@string/share"
                android:scaleX="0.6"
                android:scaleY="0.6"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_share_24"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:tint="@android:color/white" />
    
    
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWpQ2.png
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add text color to your text view (venueNameLabel):

```
android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
```